# Star secondary class Java

Tags: java, class, initialization

Okay.. so, this may sound stupid. I have two classes. Foo.class, and Bar.class

Foo.class' Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ startBar(); }
```

Bar.class' Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ echo "HI"; }
```

I want the output to be "HI".. As in, i want to start my secondary class inside the first one.. I am probably doing a horrible job at explaining this. Things to keep in mind if you do understand what i want, i don't want a process builder that starts the bar.class.. I need it to all run in the one thingy..

Comment: you can invoke Bar.main(new String[0]) directly in startBar()

Comment: or `public static void main(String[] args){ Bar.main(args); }`

Comment: Guys, why didn't you post it as answers?

Comment: `echo` is not a Java method, try `System.out.println`

Comment: lol, Sorry. I've been doing php all week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foo class

```
public static void main(String... args){
  Bar.main(args);
}
```

Bar class

```
public static void main(String... args){
  System.out.println("Hi");
}
```